# How to install MicroStrategy 10.4 on Windows Server with HotFix

Tags: installation, microstrategy, hotfix

We’d like to install MicroStrategy 10.4 on Windows Server 2016.

I understand 10.4 should be patched at least  Hotfix 5 for Windows Server 2016.

If my understanding is correct, should we apply from Hotfix 1 to 5, all hot fix, one by one ? Or only apply Hotfix 5, if it’s cumulative?

We’ve already tried applying only HotFix7, but can’t avoid component error when installed MicroStrategy Developer.

Highly appreciated any of your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I confirmed the HotFix was cumulative. 
The component error why I was doubt about it's not cumulative, was due to product bug below;

KB37106: "Failed to load control 'msiObjectExplorer' from M3OBJEXP.OCX" error message appears when launching MicroStrategy Developer 9.4.x and 10.x
https://community.microstrategy.com/s/article/KB37106-quot-Failed-to-load-control-msiObjectExplorer-from?ui-force-components-controllers-recordGlobalValueProvider.RecordGvp.getRecord=1&r=8

Just for your information, we successed to install MicroStartegy 10.4 on Windows Server 2016 as follows;

1. Install MicroStrategy 10.4
2. Apply HotFix 7 (Latest hotfix at that time)
3. Re-install DHTMLEd.ocx to avoid Developer error, according KB37106 mentioned above.

Best Regards.